keras dataset import issue
I am trying to use the keras fashion_mnist dataset but for some reason I cannot seem to load it. I am using an anaconda environment. I have tried creating new environments, redownloading tensorflow, deleting the datasets folder, but nothing seems to work.
I get this error whenever I try to run this code:


Replace your code with
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tfds.load(
    "fashion_mnist", split=["train", "test"], as_supervised=True, with_info=False
)


thanks, it seems to have worked. any idea why the original code wasn't working?

actually, when I ran it for the second time I am getting a 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)' error. It seems that it only returns the train images and labels, but not the test images and labels? why is this?
